# Trouble with Yahoo OAuth Authorization with Google / Facebook OpenID

Tags: oauth, openid, yahoo, yql

Im having a bit of trouble figuring out how to get an OAuth access token for a Yahoo user who has created an account with Google or Facebook Sign-in.  I've followed the [OAuth flow described in the documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html),  however this seems to only apply to users who have created a Yahoo account directly.

Has anyone else had trouble getting an access token for a user who has used Google or Facebook to sign into Yahoo?

I've looked at the [OAuth + OpenID flow](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-openid-auth-flow.html) but I'm having trouble at the point where I should perform discovery. How would one receive an request_token for yahoo with a user who signs in via a Google OpenID?

Anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see this happening is if Yahoo at some point allows Facebook and Google authentication in the OAuth authorization step. That would at least be the simplest way forward for an API consumer application.

The OAuth + OpenID flow will not help you I am afraid, it only works for Yahoo OpenIDs. I guess it could at least theoretically work for Google OpenIDs (if Yahoo implemented that), but Facebook is **not** even an OpenID provider.

I think Yahoo's stance on this is sound. They provide API access to users that they themselves have provisioned. I don't think you will find many API providers out there who will have a different strategy.

Comment: Jon, thanks for the reply. This does seem to make sense after reading the docs more. The difficulty from a User perspective is that now that Yahoo has allowed users to use Google/Facebook (sign-in) they have introduced a interesting problem -- Users who have used 3rd party services to create a yahoo account, but cant authorize  /authenticate themselves for use of the Yahoo Social API's. Sighh. I'll keep digging a bit, but i do think your thought may be valid.